# How to calculate last page number in Java

Tags: java

I'm implementing a pagination for my webapp, I'm leveraging hibernate over mysql. My code per retrieving last page number is:
int lastPageNumber = (int) (Math.ceil(countResults / pageSize));

countResults would be = 148
and the pageSize is 10

It yelds 14.8 obviously but lastPageNumber is now 14 instead of 15. Something is wrong and I guess it's related with the int cast, how can it be fixed and retrieve the correct answer? 15...

The rest of the code is

```
    int pageSize = 10;
    long countResults;
    int lastPageNumber;
```

Comment: Can you give a full code sample please?

Answer (score 0):

it seems changing the data types this way:

```
    double pageSize = 10;
    double countResults;
    double lastPageNumber;
```

solved my problem and the result is now correct, now I wondering if I'm wasting resources by using a double or it's the only thing I can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int Test1;
    Test1 = (int) Math.ceil(14.8);
    System.out.println("Test1 ---> " + Test1); // Test1 ---> 15

    System.out.println("Test2 ---> " + Math.ceil(148 / 10)); // Test2 ---> 14.0
    
    double Test3 = Math.ceil(148L / 10.0);
    System.out.println("Test3 ---> " + Test3); // Test3 ---> 15.0
    
    }
}
```

Comment: The one I can't understand is Test2